# How do you retrieve a client with two columns with two different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables where client information is in 'Clients', membership is in 'Membership', membership account is in 'Membership Account'.
I am trying to retrieve a client with two or more different values in column A with a certain value that is different in column B.
I am feeling like I would have to do a subquery but I am unsure as of where to add the subquery such as from the 'FROM' or the 'WHERE' clause.

Any help/guidance is appreciated as I am still trying to improve on my SQL queries.

```
         Clients
 C_ID(PK)   F_Name    L_Name
 ---       --------  ----------
 1           Josh      Abe
 2           James     Charles
 3           David     Eckartt
 4           Arnold    Erk

      Membership
M_ID(PK)     C_ID(FK)      
-----       --------
10            1
11            1
12            1
15            2
17            3
18            3
19            3
20            4
21            4
22            4
23            4

              Membership_Account
ACCT_ID(PK)     M_ID(FK)    TIER_ID(FK)    Status
-----------    ---------   -----------   ---------
2145             10             1           ACTV
2146             11             2           ACTV
2147             12             3           NOCO
2155             15             1           ACTV
2158             17             3           NOCO
2159             18             2           CANC
2177             19             4           ACTV
2179             20             1           ACTV
2181             21             3           NOCO
2182             22             4           NOCO
2183             23             2           CANC
```

I want it to display the CLIENT_ID(s) that **only** has **both** an [ACTV status for only TIER 1 & 2] and a [NOCO status for only TIER 3 & 4]

```
C_ID    ACCT_ID    TIER_ID    STATUS
-----   --------   -------    -------
  1       2145       1         ACTV
  1       2146       2         ACTV
  1       2147       3         NOCO
  4       2179       1         ACTV
  4       2181       3         NOCO
  4       2182       4         NOCO
```

I was only able to do this to get only one or the other but am unsure of how to get both to be displayed

```
SELECT Cl.C_ID, ACCT.*
FROM CLIENTS Cl
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP MEM ON MEM.C_ID = Cl.C_ID
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP_ACCOUNT ACCT ON ACCT.M_ID= MEM.M_ID
WHERE ACCT.TIER_ID in (3, 4) ---1, 2
AND ACCT.STATUS = 'NOCO' --NOCO or ACTV
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an additional join to MEMBER and MEMBERSHIP_ACCOUNT so you can identify those clients that have both criteria.  Put that in a sub-query so you can join and return all the records from MEMBERSHIP_ACCOUNT for those clients

Something like:

```
SELECT     [cl].[C_ID]
         , [ACCT].*
FROM       CLIENTS [cl]
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP [MEM]
    ON [MEM].[C_ID] = [cl].[C_ID]
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP_ACCOUNT [ACCT]
    ON [ACCT].[M_ID] = [MEM].[M_ID]
INNER JOIN (
               SELECT     DISTINCT [Cl].[C_ID]
               FROM       CLIENTS [Cl]
               INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP [MEM]
                   ON [MEM].[C_ID] = [Cl].[C_ID]
               INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP_ACCOUNT [ACCT]
                   ON [ACCT].[M_ID] = [MEM].[M_ID]
                      AND [ACCT].[TIER_ID] IN ( 1, 2 )
                      AND [ACCT].[STATUS] = 'ACTV'
               INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP [MEM1]
                   ON [MEM1].[C_ID] = [Cl].[C_ID]
               INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP_ACCOUNT [ACCT1]
                   ON [ACCT1].[M_ID] = [MEM1].[M_ID]
                      AND [ACCT1].[TIER_ID] IN ( 3, 4 )
                      AND [ACCT1].[STATUS] = 'NOCO'
           ) AS [clo]
    ON [clo].[C_ID] = [MEM].[C_ID];
```

Comment: That kind of pointed me into the right spot, but say when I want to display only a client that has to have both NOCO status in tier 3 or 4 and ACTV status in tier 1 or 2. I've tried changing that OR into an AND just so it seemed like it would be logically correct, but I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: @JohnYang my original answer would not work for what you were looking for.  I updated the answer.